# Why can the first parameter of fetch() be a Request object?

Tags: javascript, fetch

From [the API documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch)

> This defines the resource that you wish to fetch. This can either be:
>
> - A string or any other object with a stringifier — including a URL object — that provides the URL of the resource you want to fetch.
> - A Request object.

Simple question: "why"? The second parameter is `init` which seems to have all parameters that will be used to then make a `Request` object.

So:

- Why giving the possibility of using EITHER a `Request` object as first parameter, OR an URL as first  parameter and init value of a Request object as second parameter?
- Is it allowed/spec'd to have BOTH a request object as first parameter, and an init object as second parameter? I assume the answer is "no" since none of the properties of the request object are writable... but in that case, should the documentation above specify that it's either a request object, or a URL + init parameters?

Comment: 1: why? because that's the specification and it's useful to be able to make the request in either way (I have code that does both) - 2: your assumption is incorrect - you **can** have request object and init

Comment: 1. When/why would you ever use a Request object rather than passing URL/init params? 2. Wait, my assumption IS correct, I wrote "is it allowed? I assume 'no'" right?

Comment: you said `I assume the answer is "no"`  - except the answer is yes, you can

Comment: `When/why would you ever use a Request object` - reasons, I could tell you, but then I'd have to .... does it matter? I have a use case for a Request object - usually I don't use it, but in certain cases I do

Comment: In ServiceWorkers you do deal with Requests directly, having to extract the URL from these would be very painful. "since none of the properties of the request object are writable..." the init Request object is not being written on, the new Request that is created by `fetch` is not the same as the one you passed.

Comment: Ugh you are right... you can pass url + init, a request, or a request + init (!). My ultimate goal is to check if two requests are the same, regardless of how they were created. The specs made it tricky at best... I got there in the end, but buy, it's difficult code... https://github.com/mobily-enterprises/spa-fetch/blob/53a94778326469beae28486d368f44a3580678ee/index.js

Comment: Then ask about it instead, for instance I guess you could abuse the Cache API for that (`areSameRequests = async (r1, r2) => { const id = "test"+ Math.random(); const cache = await caches.open(id); await cache.add(r1); const same = !!await cache.match(r2); caches.delete(id); return same; }`)